# QFileDialog :: getSaveFileName сохранения файла в папку на диск

Tags: c++, qt

Есть затруднения с функцией `QFileDialog::getSaveFileName`. Данная функция должна окрывать диалоговое окно для выбора и сохранения файла в определенную папку.

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,
    tr("Open Address book"), "",
    tr("Address book (*.*);;All Files (*)"));
```

Данный фрагмент открывает данную папку для сохранения в нее выбранного файла.

Как выбрать и сохранить файл?

Есть поле lineEdit, где отображается путь выбранного файла для сохранения.

Comment: `QFileDialog::getSaveFileName` лишь получает путь для сохранения файла. Сохранить файл вам нужно самостоятельно, либо использовать `QFileDialog::saveFileContent`, который после получения пути ещё и сам сохранит файл. Вам непонятно как сохранить ваши данные в файл?

Comment: Данными у меня является файл, а именно путь в виджите(lineEdit),  который необходимо сохранить в папку, да, немного не понимаю как сохранять.

Comment: Мне всё ещё непонятно. Вы хотите сохранить строку из `lineEdit` в файл по пути `fileName` или скопировать файл лежащий по пути из `lineEdit` в путь `fileName`?

Comment: Да, все верно, необходимо скопировать файл лежащий по пути из lineEdit в путь fileName( в папку в которую необходимо сохранить). Вообщем сохранить его.

Comment: Вы пробовали [`QFile::copy`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfile.html#copy-1)?

Comment: Нет, не использовал, пока плохо во всем разбираюсь, учусь) Поэтому не понимаю немного)

Comment: Можно пример какой-нибудь простой, для понимания, спасибо?

Answer (score 0):

После получения пути для сохранения с помощью `QFileDialog::getSaveFileName` необходимо самостоятельно создать/сохранить конечный файл, например, с помощью `QFile`. Пример копирования файла по заданному пути:

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,
                                   tr("Open Address book"), "",
                                   tr("Address book (*.*);;All Files (*)"));
QString oldFile = lineEdit->text(); //Получаем путь старого файла
if (QFile::exists(oldFile)) {//Если старый файл существует
    QFile::remove(fileName); //Удаляем файл по пути назначения
                             //(Если он существует копирование не произойдёт)
    bool result = QFile::copy(oldFile, fileName); //Копируем старый файл по новому пути
    if (result) { 
        //Если result==true файл успешно скопирован
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142361/discussion-on-answer-by-needkvas-qfiledialog-getsavefilename--).